# In Hive, how to compare array of string with hivevar list?

Tags: sql, arrays, hive

In Hive, I have a column `date` that looks like below, array of string. I have another hivevar that look like this
`set hivevar:sunny = ('2022-12-17', '2022-12-21', '2023-01-15');`

```
|date|
|----|
|[["2022-11-14"],["2022-12-14"]]|
|[["2022-11-14","2022-11-17"],["2022-12-14","2022-12-17"]]|
|[["2022-11-21"],["2022-12-21"]]|
|[["2023-01-08"]]|
|[["2022-11-15"],["2022-12-15"],["2023-01-15"]]|
```

I want to check - for each row, if any of the value is part of the sunny list. So i want to get something like. I thought of using any, array && but they don't work in Hive. Can anyone help?

```
|result|
|----|
|false|
|true|
|true|
|false|
|true|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, (array_contains(sunny, explode(date)) as result
FROM mytable
```